# Use vb.net dll in C#. How to acces the objects in C# form from vb.net dll?

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll

I cant completly converted the vb.net code to c# code so i decided to make a vb.net dll and then add it to c# form.

But im new about this dll things and i dont know how to acces the objects in C# form. I added C# application to references in dll as i did for the dll too. But i cant still access the timer and 2 labels which are in C# application.

This is my vb.net dll

```vb
Public Class Class1
    Public Sub Bypass(block1 As String, block2 As String, ok1 As String, ok2 As String)
        Try
            Dim folderPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.Windows)
            FileSystem.FileClose(New Integer() {1})
            FileSystem.FileClose(New Integer() {2})
            If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists((folderPath & "\xspirit.sys")) Then
                FileSystem.FileOpen(1, (folderPath & "\xspirit.sys"), OpenMode.Append, OpenAccess.ReadWrite, OpenShare.LockReadWrite, -1)

            Else
                File.WriteAllBytes((folderPath & "\xspirit.sys"), New Byte() {0})
                FileSystem.FileOpen(1, (folderPath & "\xspirit.sys"), OpenMode.Append, OpenAccess.ReadWrite, OpenShare.LockReadWrite, -1)
                block1 = "Erişim Engellendi"
                MsgBox("Erişim Engellendi xspirit")
            End If
            If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists((folderPath & "\xhunter1.sys")) Then
                FileSystem.FileOpen(2, (folderPath & "\xhunter1.sys"), OpenMode.Append, OpenAccess.ReadWrite, OpenShare.LockReadWrite, -1)

            Else
                File.WriteAllBytes((folderPath & "\xhunter1.sys"), New Byte() {0})
                FileSystem.FileOpen(2, (folderPath & "\xhunter1.sys"), OpenMode.Append, OpenAccess.ReadWrite, OpenShare.LockReadWrite, -1)
                block2 = "Erişim Engellendi"
                MsgBox("Erişim Engellendi xhunter1")
            End If
        Catch exception1 As Exception
            ProjectData.SetProjectError(exception1)
            Dim ex As Exception = exception1
            ProjectData.SetProjectError(ex)
            Dim exception As Exception = ex
            ProjectData.ClearProjectError()
            ProjectData.ClearProjectError()
        End Try
        Dim p As Process()
        p = Process.GetProcessesByName("Wolfteam.bin") 'set wolfteam process
        If p.Count = 1 Then ' if wolfteam process detected
            ok1 = "XignCode Clear Başarılı"
            ok2 = "XignCode Clear Başarılı"
            MsgBox("XignCode Clear Başarılı xspirit")
            MsgBox("XignCode Clear Başarılı xhunter1")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I tried to convert C# but i cant do it completely so i tried to access the objects from my dll with this code but i couldn't do it (Yes i added it to references).

C#app.Form1(its okay until here but i cant continue this code.It doesn't accept the rest of it)

I wanted to write this actually:

```vb
C#app.Form1.Timer1.Enabled = False or C#app.Form1.label1.Text = "test"
```

I tried too:

```vb
Dim test1 As String="test" 

'then acces them from C# and then: 
vbnetdll.Class1 tt = new vbnetdll.Class1();   
label1.Text=f.vbmethod.test1;
```

But i couldn't do this to. Because it doesn't accept. What is wrong?

Comment: Sorry for not answering your question, just wondering why you cannot translate everything ?
Have you tried translate machines ?

Comment: There is absolutely no difference. C# & VB.Net both compile down to MSIL. You just reference the dll and starting using its objects like it was just any other C# dll.

Comment: Yeah but actually they didnt work well :/ and i tried to translate it myself but i couldnt translate everywhere. I know you can add dll but thanks anyway. But i asked something diffirent .)

Answer (score 0):

By default when you add an item to a form it is declared as a private field in the form's class, like this:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
```

So it's not going to accessible from another assembly that references the form. It actually has nothing to do with C# vs vb.net.

Comment: But i changed them to public.Or their events maybe :P So isnt there any way ??

Comment: Actually i checked again and i saw that i changed that. These are the codes in Form1.Designer.cs                                                                                                                                                       private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnExit;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnBrowse;
        private System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog opnPath;
        public System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        public System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
        public System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmrBypass;